# Using regex with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do something similar to the below

```
result = $.grep(data, function(e){ return e.firstname == name; });
```

with having name to be a regex expression, i.e. name starts with "Kevin*"

Comment: Are you asking for how to use a variable in a regular expression?

Comment: I didn't know I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing, I'd suggest:

```
result = $.grep(data, function(e){
             return new RegExp('^Kevin').test(e.firstName);
         });
```

To use a variable then the above can be rewritten to:

```
var name = 'Kevin';
result = $.grep(data, function(e){
             return new RegExp('^' + name).test(e.firstName);
         });
```

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp).
- [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: David, you might want to lose the $ on your regex, or add a .* in.

Comment: @Adrian: agreed, I was focused on the `==` in the posted sample, rather than the 'starts with' written in the question-text. Thanks!